# TCP/IP communication may not be possible on Android 14

Tags: java, android, wifi

When I tried updating to Android 14, an error occurred when creating a socket for a TCP/IP connection for an app I was developing.

It is implemented as follows.

```
Socket s = new Socket();
InetSocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.137.1", 50024);
s.connect(endpoint, *timeout*)
```

The stack trace is as follows.

```
   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.137.1 (port 50024) from /172.27.250.17 (port 42916) after 3000ms
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:235)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
```

I have confirmed that this can be avoided by resetting the Wi-Fi settings from the OS settings screen, but please let me know if there is a way to implement it.

Comment: `failed to connect to /192.168.137.1 (port 50024) from /172.27.250.17 ..` No that will not go and has nothing to do with Android version or Android 14. Client should be in same local net as server.

Comment: To be more specific, the 192.168.*.* range is a private address range, and so is 172.27.250.17, but they are separate, so traffic cannot be routed from 172.27.250.17 to 192.168.137.1.

Comment: thank you.
As you both pointed out, the connection destination and connection source must be on the same network.